# How can I generate a random rectangle in a canvas without touching the lines?

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

How can I make the rectangle in the canvas appear randomly anywhere in the canvas but it will never touch the division lines?  the rectangle should always be the one I wrote in the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

<script>
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
//
ctx.rect(20, 20, 40, 25);
//

ctx.moveTo(100, 0);
ctx.lineTo(100, 500);
ctx.moveTo(200, 0);
ctx.lineTo(200, 500);
ctx.moveTo(0, 75);
ctx.lineTo(300, 75);
ctx.stroke();

</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think in grid as slots:

```
    0   1   2
  |---|---|---|
0 |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
1 |   |   |   |
  |---|---|---|
```

Use `Math.random()` times the columns/lines count with `Math.floor` to get a random slot position, with this position you get the bounds of the slot using `splice(random_slot, 2)` array method.

With bounds in hands you simple deduct the rectangle size and you will have the spawn area, with some random Math you can spawn the rectangle anywhere in this bounds and you never touch the lines

example of horizontal math:

```
columns = 20, 50, 270
[0, ...columns, c.width] = [0, 20, 50, 270, width]
random_slot = 2
splice(random_slot, 2) = [50, 270]
deduce rect.width of 270 to never touch right line = [50, 270 - 40]
add and remove pixels to never touch lines = [50 + 2, 230 - 2]
final horizontal bounds = [52, 282]
apply same logic to vertical bounds
```

Final code:

```js
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    c.width = 300;
    c.height = 150;
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();

    // rectangle size
    const rect = [40, 25];

    const columns = [100, 200];
    const lines = [75];

    // draw grid lines
    columns.forEach(col => {
        ctx.moveTo(col, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(col, c.height);
    });

    lines.forEach(line => {
        ctx.moveTo(0, line);
        ctx.lineTo(c.width, line);
    });

    // choose a random slot
    const slot = {
        x: Math.floor((columns.length + 1) * Math.random()),
        y: Math.floor((lines.length + 1) * Math.random())
    };

    // create bounds to spawn point
    const bounds = {
        horizontal: [0, ...columns, c.width].splice(slot.x, 2),
        vertical: [0, ...lines, c.height].splice(slot.y, 2)
    };

    // add and remove some pixels to never touch the lines
    bounds.horizontal[0] += 2;
    bounds.vertical[0] += 2;
    bounds.horizontal[1] -= rect[0] + 2;
    bounds.vertical[1] -= rect[1] + 2;

    ctx.rect(
        bounds.horizontal[0] + (bounds.horizontal[1] - bounds.horizontal[0]) * Math.random(),
        bounds.vertical[0] + (bounds.vertical[1] - bounds.vertical[0]) * Math.random(),
        rect[0],
        rect[1]
    );

    ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>

</body>
</html>
```

Test with 150 iterations and a distance of 5 pixels of lines:

[image]